# Why would the pressure in my kitchen faucet drop overnight?

Tags: plumbing, faucet

The kitchen faucet has just noticeably decreased in pressure. No leaks anywhere. It did get a lot colder overnight, but that's the only thing that changed.

Any ideas?

Comment: How about other sinks in the house - any change in pressure there?

Comment: nope, not really

Comment: How cold - not below freezing I trust?

Comment: And do you know what kind of plumbing you have in your house?

Comment: sorry - kind of plumbing?

Comment: Yes, for instance are your pipes copper, CPVC, PEX, galvanized, etc.  Although see BMItch's response - if the clog is easily clearable (stuck in the aerator) he's spot on.

Comment: Will check aerator 2nite - not emergency. However, it's plastic. How can I tell what kind?

Comment: No, not below freezing

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1502/discussion-between-jamesson-and-the-evil-greebo)

Answer (score 5):

You have to work your way back through the plumbing system to track this down, but start with the easy fix of a clogged aerator. Many kitchen faucets have an aerator that can be easily unscrewed and they usually have a mesh that not only aerates the water, but acts as a filter. If there was any junk in the pipes that got to this point, you can just wash it off (just don't drop any parts down the drain).

Beyond that, you are left with checking and potentially replacing each valve from the sink to the next junction that doesn't have any issues.